# Persist data in C# async task - chatbot

Tags: c#, asynchronous, persist, chatbot

**Overview:**
I am working on making a chatbot and I want to store data about each of the user's posts and be able to access it to help formulate a response to the next post.

**Specific Question:**
Is there a way to create a storage class in C# such that I can do the following during the execution of an async task which continually awaits user input:

1. Receive message in Main Class
2. Store data about message in Storage Class
3. Retrieve past conversation data from Storage Class
4. Use this data to generate a response.
5. Send response (thus killing Main Class and its instantiation of Storage Class)
6. Receive new message
7. Get the past instantiation of the Storage Class with all of the old data
8. Store data about the new message in this class
9. And so on...

Note that my only concern in this question is basically how to persist the Storage Class during an async task.  I am not interested in learning anything at the moment about the other steps in the algorithm.

Comment: You should use persistent storage for this, see my answer below for an approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using Azure storage as your persistency method. The storage class will be in charge of retrieving the old data and saving the new one. The storage class itself will be stateless, but the state will be maintained in the persistant storage.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Eran. I'm actually using Azure to host my bot as well as my SQL DB's. Is there a particular storage mechanism in Azure which you think could work best? I want to essentially store a dictionary with key: value pairs. After some quick browsing it seems like a NoSQL table is the way to go. Any input?

Comment: Take a look at Azure Table storage if key value pairs is your main use :)